# How to use weak_ptr in swig?

Tags: java, swig, weak-ptr

SWIG homepage says shared_ptr is specially handled, but weak_ptr not. Does it means weak_ptr supporting has some bug/issue in SWIG? If it's ok to use, how to use it? Can anybody please give a sample .i code? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

`weak_ptr` doesn't need any special support in SWIG to use.

The operations that need special support in SWIG for `shared_ptr` are dereferencing and passing into functions. This is because you never directly dereference or create a `weak_ptr`. Instead when you're using it normally in C++ you would call the `lock()` member function to upgrade it to a full, retained `shared_ptr` or one of the other functions to query its state.

So all you need to do in practice therefore is wrap `weak_ptr` like any other template and use the existing `shared_ptr` support in conjunction. For example:

```cpp
%module test

%{
#include <memory>
%}

%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%shared_ptr(Foo)

namespace std {
template<class Ty> class weak_ptr {
public:
    typedef Ty element_type;

    weak_ptr();
    weak_ptr(const weak_ptr&);
    template<class Other>
        weak_ptr(const weak_ptr<Other>&);
    template<class Other>
        weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Other>&);

    weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Ty>&);


    void swap(weak_ptr&);
    void reset();

    long use_count() const;
    bool expired() const;
    shared_ptr<Ty> lock() const;
};
}

%inline %{
    struct Foo { };
%}
%template(FooWeakPtr) std::weak_ptr<Foo>;
```

This can be exercised with some Java:

```java
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");

    Foo a = new Foo();
    System.out.println(a);

    FooWeakPtr b=new FooWeakPtr(a);
    System.out.println(b);

    Foo c=b.lock();
    System.out.println(c);

    System.out.println(b.use_count());
    a=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println(b.use_count());
    c=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println(b.use_count());

    Foo d=b.lock();
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
```

When run this gives:

```
swig2.0 -c++ -Wall -java test.i && g++ -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux -std=c++0x -shared -o libtest.so test_wrap.cxx && javac run.java && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java run
Foo@42719c
FooWeakPtr@119298d
Foo@f72617
2
2
2
Foo@dc8569
```

(Notice here that `System.gc()` has been completely ignored by my runtime, so the attempt to lock again does actually succeed)

But it also works with the same .i file for the following Python:

```py
import test

a=test.Foo()
print a

b=test.FooWeakPtr(a)
print b

c=b.lock()
print c

print b.use_count()
a=None
print b.use_count()
c=None
print b.use_count()

d=b.lock()
print d
```

And when run gives:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python2.6 -std=c++0x -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.cxx && python run.py
<test.Foo; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Foo > *' at 0xf7419710> >
<test.FooWeakPtr; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::weak_ptr< Foo > *' at 0xf7419728> >
<test.Foo; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Foo > *' at 0xf7419740> >
2
1
0
None
```

Where the reference counting instead of GC does result in the call to `lock()` failing after the last `shared_ptr` has no more references.