# How to extend methods in SWIG that are not part of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, c++11, swig

I have a bunch of utility functions that are not part of any class, which return a `unique_ptr<MyGraph>`

I have been using the `%extend` directive for other similar cases where the function is part of a class. But `%extend` is specifically used to extend classes.

How can I extend my class-less utility functions to return a raw pointer?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't hide the unique ptr from the target language at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27699663/168175

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use `%extend` in that case. You can just create new methods and return the pointer directly. For example, if your code looks like:

```
unique_ptr<MyGraph> getMyGraph();
```

You could simply add a new method:

```
MyGraph* getGraph() { return getMyGraph().get(); }
```

If you need to control access to this when using SWIG or not, you could do this:

```
#ifdef SWIG
    MyGraph* getGraph() { return myGraphPtr.get(); }
#else
    unique_ptr<MyGraph> getMyGraph();
#endif  // SWIG
```

The 'SWIG' define is used by swig when determining which methods to expose to the target language.