# unique_ptr in class constructor with SWIG

Tags: swig, unique-ptr

I have a similar problem to [How to handle unique_ptr's with SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693812/how-to-handle-unique-ptrs-with-swig), when passing an unique_pointer as an argument in a c++ class constructor. Any idea how/if this can be done?

in the _wrap.cpp file i get

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
```

In advance thanks. :D

Comment: Make a [mcve]..

Comment: So you've done something that tried to use the (non accessible) copy constructor, but it's hard to say what/how/why or how to fix it from what's shown in your question...