# Instantiate shared_ptr objects from SWIG in Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a `BaseClass` and some derived classes

```
#ifndef TEST_H__
#define TEST_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class BaseClass
{
  public:
  virtual double eval(double x) const = 0;
};

class Square: public BaseClass
{
  public:
  double eval(double x) const {return x*x;}
};

class Add1: public BaseClass
{
  public:
  Add1(BaseClass & obj): obj_(obj) {}

  double eval(double x) const {return obj_.eval(x) + 1.0;}

  private:
  BaseClass & obj_;
};

#endif /* TEST_H__ */
```

which are treated with SWIG à la

```
%module test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

This can be used from Python like

```
import test
s = test.Square()
a = test.Add1(s)
print(a.eval(2.0))
```

What's *segfaulting*:

```
import test
a = test.Add1(test.Square())
print(a.eval(2.0))
```

Why? The `test.Square()` is not assigned to a variable, so doesn't exist anymore after the assignment to `a`, and `obj_` points to invalid storage.

To avoid such behavior, the idea to to use `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` instead of `BaseClass&`, i.e.

```
class Add1: public BaseClass
{
  public:
  Add1(std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> & obj): obj_(obj) {}

  double eval(double x) const {return obj_->eval(x) + 1.0;}

  private:
  std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> obj_;
};
```

This exact code won't work though with

```
TypeError: in method 'new_Add1', argument 1 of type 'std::shared_ptr< BaseClass > &'
```

Makes sense, too: `test.Square()` doesn't return a `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` but simply a `Square` aka `BaseClass` instance.

Is it possible to have `test.Square()` return a shared pointer `std::shared_ptr<Square>`?

Comment: It is possible to do that, but that's not what you want - you want `test.Square()` to return a shared pointer of type `std::shared_ptr<Square>` and then have `test.Add1()` implicitly convert them, because that means you get to use `Square` specific members inside Python. I'll work up a demo

Comment: That's what I intended, too. Clarified in the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SWIG has pretty good [support for `std::smart_ptr`](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_std_shared_ptr). It all happens pretty transparently, so the changes you need to make to your .i file are just:

```
%module test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <std_shared_ptr.i>

%shared_ptr(Square);
%shared_ptr(BaseClass);
%shared_ptr(Add1); // Not actually needed to make your demo work, but a good idea still

%include "test.h"
```

That was sufficient to make your demo Python code work, I also added `onlySquare()` as a member function of `Square` and adapted the demo to illustrate it:

```
import test
sq=test.Square()
test.Add1(sq) # implicitly converted to shared_ptr<BaseClass> here
sq.onlySquare()
print sq
# <test.Square; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< Square > *' at 0xf7424950> >
```

It should 'just work' for non-smart pointer arguments too, but note that now *all* Python created instances in that hierarchy will be 'smart'.

(If you're interested, I've also covered [`std::unique_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699663/168175) and [`std::weak_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24898632/168175) before).